# How to replace strings which match a regex pattern?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

i have list with numbers. I want to extract all the numbers with consecutive digits like 444,888,1111 etc.. My following python code with regex is working exactly the way I wanted.

```
import re 
numbers = ['44444', '123', '444', '454', '76587', '888', '9090', '1111', '321', '4321', '4563', '3333', '543', '765', '4567', '555', '99999', '11211','11']
conList = [] 

for num in numbers:
  if re.search(r'^(\d)\1+$',num):
    conList.append(num)

print('conList :',conList)
```

Result:

```
conList : ['44444', '444', '888', '1111', '3333', '555', '99999', '11']
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same result without using a regex pattern. How can I replace that regex pattern with some python code? (I am trying this only for educational purpose. I will post my answer if I got one.)

Comment: Get the first character of the string, then use the `all()` function to test if all the characters are equal to it.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I had already posted my code in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is my attempt to solve this problem.

```
for num in numbers:
  if len(set(num)) == 1 and len(num) >1:
    conList.append(num)
print('conList :',conList)
```

---

Or, using list comprehension

```
conList = [ num for num in numbers if len(num) > 1 and len(set(num)) == 1 ]
print('conList : %s', conList)
```

---

Or, using filter

```
conList = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1 and len(set(x)) == 1, numbers)
```

Comment: or even `filter(lambda i: len(set(i)) == 1, x)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a pythonic and fast approach of list comprehension:

```
[i for i in numbers if len(set(i)) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using list comprehensions as the following:

```
numbers = ['44444', '123', '444', '454', '76587', '888', '9090', '1111', '321', '4321', '4563', '3333', '543', '765', '4567',
     '555', '99999', '11211', '11']
conList = [x for x in numbers if x.count(x[0]) == len(x)]
print conList
```

output:

```
['44444', '444', '888', '1111', '3333', '555', '99999', '11']
```